# Jar file gets corrupted when sent over socket in Scala

Tags: java, scala, sockets, jar

I'm aware that Scala uses Java sockets, but I don't quite understand the answers from questions that people have had with the same problem but strictly in Java.

Here is my code:

I am trying to send a jar file through a socket, but when I try to open the jar file from the other side, the file seems to be corrupted. How can I fix this?

Server:

```
object server extends App {
  import java.net._
  import java.io._
  import scala.io._

  import scala.io.Source

  val server = new ServerSocket(9999)

  //Master should ping the slave actor to request for jar file
  while (true) {
      val s = server.accept()
      val in = new BufferedSource(s.getInputStream()).getLines()
      val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream())

      val filename = "mapReduce.jar"
      for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename, "ISO-8859-1").getLines)       {
          out.println(line)
          // println(line)
      }


      out.flush()
      s.close()
  }
}
```

Along with the Client:

```
object client extends App {
  import java.net._
  import java.io._
  import scala.io._
  import java.util.jar._

  val s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9999)
  lazy val in = new BufferedSource(s.getInputStream()).getLines()
  val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream())

  out.println("Give me the jar file!")
  out.flush()

  val file = new File("testmapReduce.jar")
  val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
  while(in.hasNext) {
      val buf = in.next()
      bw.write(buf)
      // println(buf)
  }


  s.close()
  bw.close()


  println("Done!")
  val jar = new JarFile(file) //this part fails
}
```

Comment: A jar file is effectively a "binary" file. You are using text oriented methods (like println and getLines) to process the file. Writing the file with println is going to insert CR and/or LF characters into your output stream. I suspect you do not want this, and that is what is causing the corruption problem. Try using print instead of println.

Comment: Thanks @mangotang, that makes a lot of sense. I tried changing println to print, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I am Java literate, but not Scala literate, so I am not familiar with some of the APIs you are using here. I *wonder* if your use of getLines may also contributing to the problem. If using getLines on a binary file, the reader will read up to any byte that looks like a CR, discard the CR, and return the line. So it is possible that getLines/getLine is filtering out any CR (which, since this is a binary file, are not truly CR, but actually just a binary value in your data that is equal to CR [decimal 13]).

Answer (score 2):

`Source`, `PrintStream` etc, are intended to deal with text, not binary data. They convert the data on both read and write in accordance with the character set they are using ("iso-8859-1" in your case).
Do not use them to read/write binary data.

If you just need to send byte, don't bother with interpreting them:

```
  val f = new FileInputStream(filename)
  val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out)
  Stream.continually(f.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(bos.write)
  f.close
  bos.close
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain exactly what this line; Stream.continually(r.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(bos.write) is doing? what does r.read refer to?

Comment: `r.read` was a typo. Should be `f.read`.
As for the rest of it, I think, if you just read what it says left to right, it would be fairly self-explanatory: continually read stuff from `f`, until you get a -1, and write it to `bos`.

Comment: I tried this but I get an java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 error, which I'm guessing I need to specify some encoding. Where do I add the encoding and what encoding do I use?

Comment: Nah, you don't need any encoding with binary data. That's the whole point.
Where are you getting the exception from? It seems that you are truncating something to one byte ...

Comment: it seems to be the client side that crashes at the while(in.hasNext) loop. Am I not processing the stream correctly? I tried removing .getLines from lazy val in but that did not help